# Method swizzling not working on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, method-swizzling

I am trying to swizzle the init methods and layout subviews of UIButton by using the following code:

```
extension UIButton {

   // Swizzled method

   @objc func xxx_init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      xxx_init(coder: aDecoder)
   }

   @objc func xxx_init(frame: CGRect) {
      xxx_init(frame: frame)
   }

   @objc func xxx_layoutSubviews() {
      xxx_layoutSubviews()
   }
}
```

And in the app delegate lunch with options method the swizzle of those methods its called:

```
private func swizzleUIButtonMethods() {
    let originalLayout = #selector(UIButton.layoutSubviews)
    let newLayout = #selector(UIButton.xxx_layoutSubviews)

    swizzleHelper.swizzleMethods(original: originalLayout, new: newLayout, type: UIButton.self)

    let originalFrame = #selector(UIButton.init(frame:))
    let newFrame = #selector(UIButton.xxx_init(frame:))

    swizzleHelper.swizzleMethods(original: originalFrame, new: newFrame, type: UIButton.self)

    let originalCoder = #selector(UIButton.init(coder:))
    let newCoder = #selector(UIButton.xxx_init(coder:))

    swizzleHelper.swizzleMethods(original: originalCoder, new: newCoder, type: UIButton.self)
}
```

with the helper function being:

```
func swizzleMethods(original: Selector, new: Selector, type: AnyClass) {
    guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(type, original),
        let newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(type, new) else {

            return
    }

    let addedMethod = class_addMethod(type, original, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod))

    if addedMethod {
        class_replaceMethod(type, new, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, newMethod)
    }
}
```

I'm using Xcode 9.0 and they seem to work well when testing on a real device however when trying to use the simulator the the initialisation of any UIButton crashes the application.

Does anyone know if this is an Xcode/Swift issue or is there something wrong with my approach?

P.S. I'm using Swift 4